# Show that if $x$, $y$, and $z$ are consecutive terms of an arithmetic sequence, and $\tan y$ is

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Show that if $x$, $y$, and $z$ are consecutive terms of an arithmetic sequence, and $\tan y$ is defined, then
$\frac{\sin x + \sin y + \sin z }{\cos x + \cos y + \cos z} = \tan y.$

How can you solve this, if x, y, and z are in an arithmetic sequence? Is there any formulas that can help? SO far, I haven't tried anything.

Comment: Yes, there are.  This link may help: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Angle_sum_and_difference_identities Also, use $x = y-r$ and $z = y+r$.

Comment: If $x=0, y=\frac{2\pi}{3}, z=\frac{4\pi}{3}$, then the left side is $\frac{0}{0}$ and the right side is $-\sqrt{3}$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $h=y-x=z-y$, then
\begin{align*}
\left[\sin(y-h)+\sin y + \sin (y+h)\right]\cos y&=\sin y\left[\cos (y-h)+\cos y +\cos(y+h)\right]\\
\left(2\sin y\cos h +\sin y\right)\cos y&=\sin y \left(2\cos y\cos h+\cos y\right)\\
\left(2\cos h +1\right)\sin y\cos y&=\sin y \cos y \left(2\cos h+1\right)
\end{align*}
Since this equality holds for all $y,h\in\mathbb{R}$ it follows $$\frac{\sin(y-h)+\sin y+\sin(y+h)}{\cos (y-h) + \cos y + \cos(y+h)}=\tan y$$
is an identity.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: if $x$,$y$ and $z$ are in arithmetic progression, then you can say that
$y-x=z-y=d$ for some $d$
Thus $y=x+d$, $z=d+y=x+2d$

With that, you can use the identities 
$sin(a+b)=\sin a\cos b+\cos a\sin b$
and $\cos(a+b)=\cos a\cos b-\sin a \sin b$.

When they tany is defined, they just mean that $\cos x+\cos y+\cos z \neq 0$.

With this information, try expressing the top an bottom parts of the quotient int terms as simply as you can.